# RoR - can I display my page header outside of %yield% in application layout?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've finally found a beautiful theme that I'd like to use, and now I'm wanting to try something here. The main page is basically one background, and the contents of the page (aside from the page header) is inside of a white backgrounded area.

Therefore, I'm wanting to know if I can actually only show the page header outside of this specific area and render the rest of the contents inside of the specific area.

Here's an example of my layouts/application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Subzero</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
    <%= render "layouts/navbar" %>
    <div id="main" role="main">
        <%= render 'layouts/ribbon' %>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
                    <h1 class="page-title txt-color-blueDark">
                        Wanting to put page title here.
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
                <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
                <% end %>
                <div class="container">
                    <%= yield %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't you store the title in a variable and echo/put/print it out the the desired location?

Comment: hmm i just tried, but how do i access the variable that is stored in a view? for example in the view i have "<% page_title = "Test" %>" but i can't use "<%= page_title %>" in the application.html file because it's undefined. i'm guessing i'd have to pass it some other way?

Comment: Modified my original post. Meant to say page title instead of the header. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails lets you have several *named yields* in addition to the "main" yield.

To create a *named yield* call yield with a symbol identifying the slot:

```
yield :title
```

To add content to the slot you would use `content_for`.

```
content_for :title, 'Hello World!'
```

One cool trick is that you can declare a yield in your layout and then assign the content when your main yield renders:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<header>
  <%= yield :header %>
</header>
<div id="main">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

app/views/foo/show.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  <h1>Hello from "foo/show"</h1>
<% end %>

<p>This is the main content</p>
```

This would render:

```
<header>
  <h1>Hello from "foo/show"</h1>
</header>
<div id="main">
  <p>This is the main content</p>
</div>
```

Another alternative is to use instance variables:

```
def new
  @title = 'Hello World'
end
```

Which you would print in your layout:

```
<%= @title || "Welcome to my rails app" %>
```

The latter is a bit more flexible for simple strings like a page title since `content_for` cannot be called from your controllers (well kind of). While `content_for` is a powerful tool for creating dynamic chunks in your layouts and views and can even be used to set up a sort of inheritance in your views.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a "best practice" way of doing it, but basically I added a function in helpers/application.html called function which looks like this:

```
#helpers/application.html.erb

def pg_header(header)
   @page_header = header
end
```

and in my view, I have something that looks like this:

```
<% pg_header("Here's my page header") %>
```

And in my layouts/application.html, it calls @page_header since I don't think I can access any variables in the view until %yield% is issued. Not 100% sure but this is working for me. Any better solutions would be great. Thanks guys.

Comment: your missing a ")" bruv, its supposed to be: <% pg_header("Here's my page header") %>

Comment: Fixed and working. Thanks. Had it correct already but typod in here

Comment: I'm sure its not a "best practice" but I'm sure its not going to stump performance. Oh and  Ignore my last comment i just saw your edit.